# include the amp.h lib in a c++ programm under linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, g++, gpu

I want to use the amp.h library in my c++ program  programmed and running on Linux;

So I tried to include the amp.h lib in an empty .cpp file and tried to compile it with the g++ compiler via console. Below you can find the .cpp file and the commands i used to compile:

```
#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_graphics.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace concurrency;
using namespace concurrency::graphics;

int main()
{ 
    return 0 ;
}
```

So the answer of the compiler was that amp.h no such file or directory;

I tried to find a installation command like

```
sudo apt-get install amp.h
```

But I did not get any good results.

The compile was:

```
g++ "filename".cpp
```

Comment: Search in AMD webpage, or just in Google, about C++ AMP support for linux.

Comment: I searched for that topic and i also found some more questions about c++amp on stckoverflow with the same intension but there is no compiler on linux yet that can handle the library include as far as i understand.

Comment: I think there is one project under development to support it, but I ignore the current status: https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/hcc.

Comment: There are new Open Source Projects that are independent from windows:

https://de.slideshare.net/winlee39566/c-amp-on-linux

I have to chekc it out over the weekend but it seems to be an answer to my question from 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add amp.h Because it have following **System Requirements**

- Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, or Windows Server 2012
- DirectX 11 Feature Level 11.0 or later hardware
- For debugging on the software emulator, Windows 8 or Windows Server
  2012 is required. For debugging on the hardware, you must install the
  drivers for your graphics card.

Comment: Where is the source of those requirements, please?

Comment: Can i provide you the link to official documentation.